# didn't know how to use sstring

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand how to use `NSString`, can someone please fix my mistake?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {            

    @IBOutlet var ship: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var mothership: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var enemy: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var missel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lives: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startb: UIButton!

    nsstring *touch;
    String *livesstring;
    nsstring *scorestring;

    nstimer *enemyMovmentTimer;
    nstimer *missileMovemmentTimer;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    -(IBAction)startGame:(id)sender;

    }
}
```

Comment: It's `NSString`, not `nsstring`. Code is case-sensitive

Comment: And you're mixing Objective-C and Swift together

Comment: where? can you help me?

Comment: on swift you define a String variable like this `var a :String`

Comment: `where` everywhere. If you can't tell the difference between the two languages I suggest you continue to learn before using Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {            

    @IBOutlet var ship: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var mothership: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var enemy: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var missel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lives: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startb: UIButton!

    var touch = NSString()
    var livesstring = String()
    var scorestring = NSString()

    var enemyMovmentTimer = NSTimer()
    var missileMovemmentTimer = NSTimer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func startGame(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

}
```